# How to fix "no package called textdata" error?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, tidytext

I am trying to run sentiment analysis in R. I have installed tidytext and it is in the correct library with all other packages.

However, when I run

```
get_sentiments("afinn")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘textdata’
```

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: try `install.packages("textdata", dependencies=TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that the package is missing from your libraries. You need to install it with `install.packages("textdata")`.